Are usernames unique in PTCGP?
In Pokémon Trading Cards Game Pocket I've just changed my username to one of the gym leaders of the Sinnoh region and I've been surprised it wasn't already taken.
So, can two people have the same username? Can someone confirm? Maybe if you have a friend who also plays and you both want the same username?

Your most recent edits have completely changed the original question. If you have a new question (why a specific username was not allowed), you can ask a new question.

@ryanyuyu Yeah, I know, I thought about it. Do you think it would be worth it to create a new separate question for restricted usernames? I kind of am already satisfied with the results I got (I think the conclusion is: usernames aren't unique, and some of them are restricted). Is it worth making a new question?

That's up to you. If you are satisfied with the answer then don't ask a new question. But I really do think you should undo the edits that basically ask a second question and make the top answer less relevant.

@ryanyuyu Yeah, I see how my edits invalidated my question or the answers. I'm going to create a new question. Thanks for your honest feedback.

This was also asked on Reddit. OP chose a very common name "Ash Ketchum" and wondered if anyone else did this.

Considering the add friend feature is your account code, I’d assume they allow multiple players to have the same usernames.


You can remake multiple accounts with the same name. This is what rerollers do before linking so no limit on names.

You can see that in the comment section a couple of users both used "Ash Ketchum", so it seems that the usernames are not unique.

I've just edited the question because I've remembered a fact that happened to me

@xtropicalsoothing that seems to be a different reason
